# split string and create pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>
```

I have  above string, and I have to build pagination, the flag is the `pagi` class. I know how to do it if above html is an actual html, but it's string, I can't use jquery `.find('pagi')`

Need help, I'm stuck.

Comment: `.find('.pagi')` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wrap the string using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) and then use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find) method.

```
var $ele = $(str).find('.pagi');
```

```js
var str = '<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>';

var $ele = $(str).find('.pagi');

console.log($ele.length);
$ele.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow cool! but in the end how will my pagination logic be like?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson :  you need to implement your own logic :)

Answer (score 0):

you can easly convert the string into dom and select using querySelector

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><p class="pagi">page 1 content</p><p class="pagi">page 2 content</p><p class="pagi">page 3 content</p></div>'
var pagi =  div.querySelectorAll('.pagi');
```

Comment: OP is asking jQuery.